# POST_NOTIFICATIONS permission dialog not showing (Android 13, targetSdkVersion=33)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-permissions, android-13

There are many questions on this topic already, I know. However, none of the answers I have found so far resolves the issue for me.

The problem is ActivityCompat.requestPermissions does not trigger a popup, asking the user to give permission for notifications.

Setup:

- Testing on physical device (Android 13, Samsung Galaxy S22 and Samsung Galaxy A51)
- targetSdkVersion = 33
- compileSdkVersion = 33
- minSdkVersion = 23
- AndroidManifest has permission: `<uses-permission` `android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>`

Activity declared in AndroidManifest

```
        <activity android:name=".PostNotificationActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Click on Enable Notification button:

```
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS),
                    POST_NOTIFICATION_PERMISSION_CODE)

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS),
                    POST_NOTIFICATION_PERMISSION_CODE)
            }
        }
```

and the callback is like so:

```
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

        when(requestCode) {
            POST_NOTIFICATION_PERMISSION_CODE -> {
                if (grantResults.size > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }

                return
            }
        }
    }
```

I have stepped through the code via the debugger, and can confirm that on first button click **requestPermissions** is called but no popup on device and **onRequestPermissionsResult** is also not trigger as well.
And when again clicked the button **requestPermissions** is called with no popup on device but **onRequestPermissionsResult** is triggered now with **Permission Denied** and when press back previous activity is freezed.

I have also tried using the new ActivityResultLauncher, but the behaviour is same no popup on device.

Comment: Hi, do you have notification permission declared in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Once the permission is granted requestPermissions() will not popup a dialog but trigger the onRequestPermissionsResult directly. Well not using ActivityCompat but registerForActivityResult(). new RequestPermission().

Comment: Yes notification permission is declared in AndroidManifest.xml
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>`

Comment: Yes I have also tried
`registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission())`

Comment: This might help you handle the edge cases of requesting permissions: https://github.com/LouisCAD/Splitties/tree/main/modules/permissions